# Creating a Dynamic Chess board (Grid) using Xamarin forms & c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a dynamic chessboard based on user input(The user inputs 10x 8y and it establishes a 10x8 board). I can't seem to keep the grid inside its own area and fill the full area provided. I was wondering how I would fix this issue

xaml code

```
    <StackLayout >
        <StackLayout x:Name="User_Input" BackgroundColor="Green">
            <Label Text="Enter Length of Grid" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Body"/>
            <Entry x:Name="xEntry" Placeholder="0" />
            <Label Text="Enter Width of Grid" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Body"/>
            <Entry x:Name="yEntry" Placeholder="0"  />
            <Button x:Name="btnStart" Clicked="btnStart_Clicked" Text="Start"/>

        </StackLayout>
        
        <Frame x:Name="Game" BorderColor="Black">

            <Grid x:Name="Game_Grid"  BackgroundColor="RoyalBlue" Margin="0" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="100">
                


            </Grid>
               
        </Frame>

    </StackLayout>
```

C# Code

```
private void btnStart_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //User_Input.IsVisible = false;
            //Game.IsVisible = true;
            int max_x =  Int32.Parse(xEntry.Text);
            int max_y = Int32.Parse(yEntry.Text);
            cellGrid main = new cellGrid(max_x,max_y);
            for (int y = 0; y < max_y; y++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
                c.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
                Game_Grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);   
               for(int x = 0;  x < max_x; x++)
                {
                    RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
                    r.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
                    Game_Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
                    Label cell = new Label { 
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
                        ,VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                        WidthRequest = Game_Grid.WidthRequest / max_x,
                        HeightRequest = Game_Grid.HeightRequest / max_y,
                    };
                    cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Black);
                    Game_Grid.Children.Add(cell, x,y);
                }
            }



        }
```

[Image of the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2uqq.png)

Comment: you are creating too many rows and cols.  Do NOT doo this using a nested loop.  Just have one loop create the rows, then a 2nd loop to create the cols.  THEN use the logic you have to create the labels within the nested loop

Comment: To add to Jason's comment: Your c# code should mimic what you would see in xaml. Look at any Grid example. You'll see a set of RowDefinitions. And a set of ColumnDefinitions. Are they nested in xaml, with rows inside of columns? No. So don't nest them in c#.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this issue. I was wondering if you would also happen to know how I would be able to keep the Squares at a consistent value.  Because when I input a large value like 8x8 the Squares near the edge change size

Comment: don't use Auto for the size, use Star

Comment: i have attempted star as ``` c.Width = new GridLength(Game_Grid.WidthRequest / max_x, GridUnitType.Star);``` but it won't fill the full area of the grid

Comment: [Output](https://i.imgur.com/xD6x7ny.png)

Comment: Never mind I found out the issue. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Cell must have its .GridRow and .GridColumn set